# How can I position these divs horizontally?

Tags: jquery, html, css, arrays, jquery-ui-sortable

I cannot figure out how to place the lists horizontal, i have played with almost everything i would really appreciate it if someones gives me their advice.
http://jsfiddle.net/py3DE/74/

```
<div class="source">
<div class="item"><span class="closer"></span>s1</div>
<div class="item"><span class="closer"></spanHow>s2</div>
<div class="item"><span class="closer"></span>s3</div>
</div>
<div class="target">
<div class="empty"></div>
<div class="empty"></div>
<div class="empty"></div>
<div class="empty"></div>
<div class="empty"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In general, for something like this, you would use a `<ul>...</ul>` element containing `<li>` elements, styled with `display:inline`. Styling divs with `display:inline` is traditionally problematic - for a long time many browser versions did not behave predictably. Situation may be better now but most people would still use a `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of stuff you need to add width to the source.
See http://jsfiddle.net/harendra/2phuW/1/

You need to change css in following way.

```
.source{
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
    width:200px;
}
.item{
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.item { height:20px; margin: 5px; padding:5px; border:1px solid gray; background-color: #cd8; position: relative; display: inline-block;}

.target > div {
    width: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cf59n/)

Answer (score 1):

(can't vote up for the previews answer who are realy good) but I will just add

```
.target > div {
    width: 25px;
    height:30px;
    padding:none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

to prevent the new vertical position when element is dropped.

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Cf59n/2/

(I'v just add this line from the fiddle of the previews answer

Answer (score 0):

Your width attribute on the `source` class is restricting the list from going horizontal.  Get rid of this attribute, or make it wider, and add `display:inline` to the `item` class and you should be on your way.